# Can I charge 2S 18650 battery pack with a BMS and a 9V wall adapter?

Tags: battery-charging, bms

I have [this cheap 2S BMS board](https://au-m.banggood.com/2S-3A-Li-ion-Lithium-Battery-Protection-Board-7_4v-8_4V-18650-Charger-BMS-for-Li-ion-Lipo-Battery-p-1538059.html?rmmds=search&act_poa=SKUC55335&cur_warehouse=CN) that I want to use to charge a 2S 18650 battery pack (two 18650 in series.)

Can I use this BMS board with a 9V wall adapter to charge my battery pack? I want to make a portable battery pack for a school project.

Answer (score 1):

No you must have a battery charge controller that is suited for lithium ion batteries.

Just connecting a voltage regulated power supply to a battery pack with BMS will result in an incorrect charging cycle and incorrect voltage to the batteries. Most batteries need a constant current charging cycle then constant voltage charging cycle, which a battery charging controller provides.

Comment: but i have seen a lot of videos you tube , guys doing it but it's sad nobody told this truth, Thanks man, can you please mention what i need to do to make a portable/rechargeable 2s 18650 battery pack without asking me to post a different question :-)

Answer (score 0):

For charge it, i recommend using 2s charging module, i dont remember its model
But it had two mode, 1s and 2s battery charge
And then you can just charge it with 12v or maybe 9v wall adapter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).